# AEM Connected assets setup / configuration

Tags: configuration, aem, assets, remote-server, dam

When trying to configure connected assets in AEM, on the Sites instance, the connected configuration save option gets disabled after the initial setup. 
Not able to save subsequent edits to the configuration, even when trying with admin credentials.

Is there any configuration to check why the save is disabled? Where under the jcr is this configuration stored?

Comment: After some search found that the configuration is stored under the node /conf/global/settings/dam/remotedam/configuration/jcr:content, which can be edited directly

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is stored under the node /conf/global/settings/dam/remotedam/configuration/jcr:content

We can directly make edits to the properties under this node. However the remote assets instance password is stored as encrypted value. In case edit is required on the password filed, the best option as of now seems to be delete the jcr:content node at this path and reconfigure it through the UI.

Deleting the jcr:content node at this path is the only option I could find to enable the save option on the UI.

This certainly is a bug in this newly introduced feature in AEM 6.5. Hopefully will get addressed in a service pack.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945996/1592801,

- You don't need to delete the configuration node
- Re-entering the password works - and that is working as designed.
- The save button is disabled, because there have been no edits in the form to save. Once you make a change, you should be able to see the button enabled.